# Duality Theorem for Minimum Distance Problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, duality-theorems, optimal-control

The minimization of the one-norm can be stated as:
$$
\min_{u\in\ell_1} \|u\|_1 \qquad \text{subject to} \qquad Au=b,
$$
where $u\in\mathbb{R}^m = [u_1,u_2,...,u_m]^\intercal$ is the sequence that we want to minimize the one-norm of, with the equality constraints given above, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This gives $n$ constraints on $u$. There is a theorem, which comes from the Hahn-Banach theorem, that states this problem is equivalent to the maximization problem in the dual space
$$
\max_{\|A^\intercal x\|_{\infty}\leq 1} x^\intercal b
$$
Now, the expression $\|A^\intercal x\|_{\infty}\leq 1$ gives $N$ inequality constraints and forms a polyhedron from which the optimal value $x^*$ in the dual space must adhere in. The theorem also states that if the maximum is achieved for some $x^*\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $\|A^\intercal x\|_{\infty}=1$, and the minimum is achieved for some $u^*\in\mathbb{R}^m$, then $u^*$ and $x^*$ are aligned.

This means that whenever equality is *not* met (for some $k = 1,2,...,m$), the value for $u_k = 0$. I understand this in an intuitive way, but how can this be proven more rigorously? Also, what I really don't understand is how to actually find the value of $u_k$ when equality *is* met.

To further illustrate my point, I ran a simple code in MATLAB to solve this problem. I had the following numbers:
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
29 & 11 & 4 & 1\\
18 & 7 & 3 & 2\\
29 & 11 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad 
b = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which means that $u\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$. The output of the code gives the solution:
$\|u^*\|_1 = x^{*\intercal}b = 0.3$, as well as 
$$
x^* = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-0.2\\ 0.7\\ -0.2
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad u^* = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.025\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0.275
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad A^\intercal x^* = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0.5\\0.5\\1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From what I wrote before, we can see that when the components of $\|A^\intercal x^*\|_\infty = 1$, then $u^*_k$ is a constant nonzero value, but when this condition is not met, there is no alignment, and $u^*_k = 0$. My question is how do we get from $x^*$, which is easily found from a LP solver, to $u^*$. There must be something simple that I am missing here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the principle of complementary slackness, by chance?

Comment: Yea I'm aware of it, but I've only seen it done for problems that minimize some $c^\intercal x$ in the primal space and maximize $y^\intercal b$ in the dual space. I've never seen it done before for minimizing an $\ell_1$ norm

Comment: Understood. So you can get that here if you converted the primal problem to LP form. There are multiple ways to do this; for instance,
$$\begin{array}{ll}_{u,v} \text{minimize} & \sum_i v_i \\ \text{subject to} & A u = b \\ & -v \leq u \leq v\end{array}$$Note that if you look at the dual of this, it will have a different structure, but you will almost certainly see its equivalence to the $\ell_\infty$ version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x^*$ and $u^*$ be optimal solutions to the two problems. Strong duality means that both problems have equal objectives; so 
$$\|u^*\|_1 = \langle b, x \rangle = \langle A u^*, x^* \rangle = \langle u^*, A^T x^* \rangle = \langle u^*, y^*\rangle$$
where $y^*=A^Tx^*$. Note that $\|y^*\|_\infty \leq 1$—in fact, it's not hard to see that it must be true that $\|y^*\|_\infty = 1$, because otherwise I can just scale $x^*$ to make it so (implying that the original $x^*$ would not have been optimal).

Now let's keep going to the right using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\langle u^*, y^* \rangle \leq \|u^*\|_1 \|y^*\|_\infty = \|u^*\|_1.$$
Not surprisingly we're back where we started. But this is important, because for a given nonzero $u^*$, there are only certain values of $y^*$ that can satisfy the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with equality. Specifically, it must be the case that
$$u_i^* = 0 ~\text{or}~ y^*_i = \mathop{\textrm{sign}}(u^*_i), \quad i=1,2,\dots, n$$

Comment: I understand what you’re saying, it makes sense. But I still am not seeing how one could get $u_i$ from this. From what I see, the Cauchy-Schwarz constraints give you the $y_i$ values *given* the signs of the $u_i$ values. But how would we recover the control instead?

Comment: I see your dilemma. A couple of ideas. First, if you know an element of $u$ is zero, you can eliminate it from the equality constraints; eventually you may get to a nonsingular linear system. That might even be guaranteed to happen under mild conditions. Secondly, even if you cannot, you do know the signs of the nonzero values so the 1-norm just becomes a linear combination, and you have reduced the problem to an LP. Finally, are you assuming it ought to be easier than that; if so, why?

Comment: It's not really any easier with a simple LP. You get the pattern of zeros and nonzeros, sure, but not the values.

Comment: Your first comment is actually what I’ve been working on! Really nice that you got that. But yea, I’ve been developing a formulation where I delete the miscellaneous columns and reduce the system to something like $\tilde{A}\tilde{u}= x_f$, where $\tilde{A}$ is square and non singular. It turns out that there will be EXACTLY $n$ values in the optimal control $u^*$ that are not zero. Why that happens I have no clue, but this means that $u^*$ can be found from the resulting $n$ by $n$ inverse times $x_f$.

Comment: Well to be fair, eliminating the zeros is akin to finding the optimal basis in LP land. So what you're describing is indeed the exactly what the simplex algorithm tries to achieve in LP.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help. I wonder though, is there any analytical solution to this? Maybe a different approach or something

Comment: Definitely no analytic solution.